# Trying to create a namespace in an AWS EKS cluster with kubectl - Getting: Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to create a namespace in an AWS EKS cluster and keep getting an error.

I can do everything I want using the default namespace yet when I try to create a new namespace name I am forbidden.

It must be something that I have done incorrectly with the user "thera-eks".
Perhaps the role binding?

It looks like I gave the role access to everything since in the rules I gave it the * wildcard.

The command I use is -

```
kubectl create namespace ernie
```

The error I get is -

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "thera-eks" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

My role.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: full_access
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

My rolebinding.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: full_access_role_binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: thera-eks
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: full_access
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The aws-auth config map is:

```
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::9967xxxxxxxx:role/eksctl-ops-nodegroup-linux-ng-sys-NodeInstanceRole-346VJPTOXI7L
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - eks-role
      - system:master
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::9967xxxxxxxx:role/thera-eks
      username: thera-eks
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::9967xxxxxxxx:user/test-ecr
    username: test-ecr
    groups:
    - eks-role
```

The AWS IAM permissions JSON for the role "thera-eks" is -

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have created a `Role` but `Role` only applies in the context of _a Namespace_ -- a `ClusterRole` is the thing which spans across Namespaces (and thus would be capable of creating a Namespace itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mdaniel and @PEkambaram are right but I would like to expand and back it up with the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) for better understanding:

> An `RBAC` `Role` or `ClusterRole` contains rules that represent a set
> of permissions. Permissions are purely additive (there are no "deny"
> rules).
>
> A `Role` always sets permissions within a particular namespace; when
> you create a `Role`, you have to specify the namespace it belongs in.
>
> `ClusterRole`, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource. The
> resources have different names (`Role` and `ClusterRole`) because a
> Kubernetes object always has to be either namespaced or not
> namespaced; it can't be both.
>
> `ClusterRoles` have several uses. You can use a `ClusterRole` to:
>
> - define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted within individual namespace(s)
> - define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted across all namespaces
> - define permissions on cluster-scoped resources
>
> **If you want to define a role within a namespace, use a `Role`; if you want to define a role cluster-wide, use a `ClusterRole`.**

You will also find an example of a [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: secret-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

and for a [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrolebinding-example):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets-global
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: manager # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The linked docs will show you all the necessary details with examples that would help understand and setup your RBAC.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the detailed explanation!!!

Answer (score 0):

User "thera-eks" doesnt have permissions to create namespace.

Use the below command to check if you are allowed to create namespace

```
kubectl auth can-i create namespace
```

You need to have Cluster level permissions to create namespace object. Define clusterrole and map the user in clusterrolebindings